# SSL - heroku certs:add - no certificate given

Tags: ssl, heroku

I am having some difficulty adding a SSL certificate to my heroku hosted domain.

I have previously had a certificate loaded, but for a naked domain (i.e. without the www). I need to update this to the www domain. The command I am running is as follows:

```
heroku certs:add ../server.crt ../server.key --app [app name]
```

However I am always getting the response:

```
Resolving trust chain... failed
 !    No certificate given.
```

I have generated the key and certificate several times, but always seem to get the same response. I'd appreciate some help in understanding where I might be wrong.

My certificate and key files exist (in the parent directory) as follows:

server.crt

```
Web Server CERTIFICATE
————————

——BEGIN CERTIFICATE——
[Certificate string]
——END CERTIFICATE——


INTERMEDIATE CA:  
———————————————————

——BEGIN CERTIFICATE——
[Intermediate CA]
——END CERTIFICATE——
```

server.key

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
[private key]
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: How did you solve this ?